# Django NoReverseMatch with correct arguments

Tags: python, django

After looking through pages of similar answers, I regret to say that I'm still stumped.  I'm pretty sure it's an error in the urlconf but anywho, here's all the relative info:

URLCONF in APP

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^tenants/$', views.tenant_index, name = 'tenant_index'),
url(r'^(?P<property_alias>[\w\-]+)/$', views.property_detail, name='property_detail'),
url(r'^tenants/(<?P<first>\w+)/(<?P<last>)\w+/$', views.tenant_detail, name = 'tenant_detail'),)
```

index.html

```
    <h1> List of Tenants</h1>
    {% for tenant in tenants %}
    <ul> {{ tenant}} </ul>
    <h2><a href="{% url 'tenant_detail' first=tenant.first_name last=tenant.last_name %}"> details </a> </h2>
    {% endfor %}
```

segment of views.py

```
def tenant_detail(request, first, last):
    tenant = Tenant.objects.filter(first_name__startswith = first,
        last_name__startswith = last)
    tenant = get_object_or_404(Tenant, pk=tenant[0].pk)
    return render(request, 'my_properties/tenants/tenant_detail.html', {'tenant': tenant})
```

the error itself is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /properties/tenants/

    Reverse for 'tenant_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'last': u'no', u'first': u'yay'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['properties/tenants/(<?P<first>\\[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/(<?P<last>)\\[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+/$']

    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/properties/tenants/
    Django Version:     1.6
    Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    


    Reverse for 'tenant_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'last': u'no', u'first': u'yay'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['properties/tenants/(<?P<first>\\[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/(<?P<last>)\\[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+/$']
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Seems like I'm following the correct general procedure

Comment: do you hace a '<' extra en this regex?

Comment: could you try `url(r'^tenants/(?P<first>\w+)/(?P<last>)\w+/$', views.tenant_detail, name = 'tenant_detail'),)` ??

Comment: holy snap, that worked.  I think i left the '<' from earlier experiments without realizing it.  Thanks!

Comment: what does 'snap' means?

Comment: The close paren for `last` is also misplaced - your \w+ is outside it so your view will always get the empty string as that argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your regexp.
The `\w+` of the 'last' group was outside the bracket, and there is a typo on the named group syntax.

This should work: `r'^tenants/(?P<first>\w+)/(?P<last>\w+)/$'`